# Does bash (or any shell, for that matter) have an 'overwrite' mode?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, bash-history

I'm running similar commands on (e.g.) a set of files. As an example, let's say I'm doing something like this (this isn't what I'm doing, it's just an example):

```
> cat path/to/dir/file01.txt
  [file contents]
> another-command path/to/dir/file01.txt
  [more output]
> cat path2/to/dir/file02.txt
  [file contents, from which I can tell I should do something different]
> different-command path2/to/dir/file02.txt
  [yet more output]
> cat path3/to/dir/file03.txt
  [file contents]
> another-command path3/to/dir/file03.txt
  [output]
```

etc.

It would be convenient if, after using the <kbd>↑</kbd> key to return to a previous command, I could overwrite non-duplicated text ― like the file name, or a common part of the path — rather than having to delete it and retype it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash has that but it isn't bound to any key by default.

Add the line

```
Control-o: overwrite-mode
```

to your `$HOME/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to toggle between insert mode and override mode.

See the `READLINE` section in the [Bash manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html) for more.

Comment: When I try running the command `overwrite-mode` (whether or not it's bound to a key) I get the error `overwrite-mode: command not found`. I tried a couple of other commands from that page (e.g. `tab-insert`) with the same result. Weird.

Comment: @WilsonF it is not a command, but the name of a [readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) mode. You add the line given by Florian to `~/.inputrc`, and the readline library, on bash's startup, will read them.

Comment: Ohhhhh... <light bulb!>

Comment: Okay, it worked perfectly! Plus I now have a much deeper understanding of `bash`. Awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Not what you asked for directly, but you can use various forms of [history interaction](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) to simplify your task:

```
$ cat path/to/dir/file01.txt
cat: path/to/dir/file01.txt: No such file or directory
$ different-command !$
different-command path/to/dir/file01.txt
bash: different-command: command not found
$ cat !$:s/1/2/
cat path/to/dir/file02.txt
cat: path/to/dir/file02.txt: No such file or directory
$ ^2^3
cat path/to/dir/file03.txt
cat: path/to/dir/file03.txt: No such file or directory
$ !-3:s/1/3/
different-command path/to/dir/file03.txt
bash: different-command: command not found
$ !diff:s/3/4/
different-command path/to/dir/file04.txt
bash: different-command: command not found
```

Ignoring the errors, each time I used history interaction (`!$`, `!$:s/1/2`, `^2^3`), you can see how `bash` expanded it.

- `!$` - the last word of the previous command
- `:s/1/2` - replace the first occurrence of `1` with `2` in the selected word (in this case, that was `!$` again).
- `^2^3` - replace the first occurrence of `2` with `3` in the entire previous command.
- `!-3` - run the third-last command.
- `!diff` - run the last command that started with `diff`.

Comment: As you say, not precisely what I was going for, but still super useful (though I'll probably need to train myself to use it a little at a time).

Answer (score 5):

You can bind a key to a readline directive in `$HOME/.inputrc`.

```
"code": overwrite-mode
```

To discover the code generated by a specific key press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>and<kbd>V</kbd> together then hit that key.
For example when you hit the `Ins` (insert) key you see `^[[2~`.
Beware that `^[` is just the screen representation for ESC, which is represented with `\e` for readline.
Therefore you should add the following line to `$HOME/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[2~": overwrite-mode
```

and restart bash.

Comment: I upvoted this, because you went to the trouble, and it is correct, but isn't it essentially the same as the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, only with some additional details on binding any chosen key.

Comment: Well, if you press Ctrl-o after Ctrl-v, you get "^O" which does not work.